# How can I access multipage API with Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on a project and I need to get information from an API. The problem is that this API has 25 pages separately and I don't know how to access all of them at once.

I have this class that has the Map `_queryParameters` but when I run the application, it only gets the last page in the map, the 4th in this case.

How could I get all the pages?

```dart
class Api {

  final String _baseUrl = 'rickandmortyapi.com';
  final String _charactersPath = '/api/character/';
  final Map<String, String> _queryParameters = <String, String>{
    'page': '2',
    'page': '3',
    'page': '4'
  };

  final String _charactersJsonKey = 'results';

  final HttpClient _httpClient = HttpClient();

  Future<List<Character>> getCharacters() async {
    final uri = Uri.https(_baseUrl, _charactersPath, _queryParameters);
    final response = await _getJson(uri);

    if (response == null || response[_charactersJsonKey] == null) {
      print('Api.getCharacters(): Error while retrieving characters');
      return null;
    }

    return _convert(response[_charactersJsonKey]);
  }

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> _getJson(Uri uri) async {
    try {
      final request = await _httpClient.getUrl(uri);
      final response = await request.close();

      if (response.statusCode != HttpStatus.OK) {
        print('Api._getJson($uri) status code is ${response.statusCode}');
        return null;
      }

      final responseBody = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
      return json.decode(responseBody);
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print('Api._getJson($uri) exception thrown: $e');
      return null;
    }
  }

  List<Character> _convert(List charactersJson) {
    List<Character> characters = <Character>[];

    charactersJson.forEach((character) {
      characters.add(Character.fromJson(character));
    });

    return characters;
  }
}
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot specify multiple values for a single key in a map (neither can you specify multiple values for a single query parameter).

You should instead make your `getCharacters` adaptive by adding a parameter for the `page` value:

```dart
Future<List<Character>> getCharacters(int page) async {
  final uri = Uri.https(_baseUrl, _charactersPath, <String, String>{
    'page': '$page',
  });
  ...
```

Now, you can simply call your `getCharacters` method multiple times like this:

```dart
Future<List<Character>> getAllCharacters() async {
  final List<Character> result = [];
  for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    result.addAll(await getCharacters(i));
  }
  return result;
}
```